# Postgres 10 Partitioning - Parent Table Not Visible

Tags: postgresql, phpstorm, pgadmin, postgresql-10

I've upgraded to Postgres 10 and I'm planning to deploy some partitioned tabled using the new declarative partitioning syntax:

```sql
-- Create a parent table
create table test(
  name text,
  created timestamp with time zone default now()
) partition by range(created);

-- Create a partition
create table test_2017 partition of test
   for values from('1 JAN 2017') to ('1 JAN 2018');
```

I'd like to be able to reference the parent table in my functions and queries, but only the partitioned tables seem to get resolved by my tools. In both PhpStorm 2017.3 RC and BigSQL's PGAdmin III schema browsers, the table listings both show the partition, but not the parent table. In PhpStorm's editor, I get an "unresolved table" warning whenever I reference "test", however insert/select queries still work.

Have I missed something, or are the tools not yet fully compatible with partitioning?

Comment: pgadmin III is dead. Might try pgadmin 4 instead. Not sure about PhpStorm, but you might be able to work with DBeaver.

Comment: @AlexanderMP BigSQL are keeping pgadmin III updated and compatible with 10, but you're right, I should try pgadmin 4.

Comment: @AlexanderMP yep, pgadmin 4 v2 works as I would expect

Comment: check if it's in Schemas tab of your postgres connection settings in PhpStorm